# Avoiding passing large arrays across functions

Tags: arrays, matlab, function

Consider the following minimal test problem

```
function [P1,P2,P3] = test()
D = 20;
paths = 1e6;
P1 = zeros(1,paths); P2 = zeros(1,paths); P3 = zeros(1,paths);
G = @(x,flag) A(x,flag);

tic
for i = 1:paths 
   X = randn(1,100);
   P1(i) = G(X,1);
end
t1 = toc;

tic
for i = 1:paths 
   X = 2*randn(1,100);
   P2(i) = G(X,1);
end
t2 = toc;  

tic
a = function(@(x) A(x,0));
for i = 1:paths 
   X = a*randn(1,100);
   P3(i) = G(X,1);
end
t1 = toc;

function [A] = A(x,flag)
A = sum(x);
if flag==1
   A = A/length(x);
end

function [B] = B(x,flag)
B = 0;
for 1:length(x)
   B = (-1)^i * x(i);
if flag==1
   B = B/length(x);
end
```

So it is a function which runs the either function A or function B on some different data. However my problem is that every time I call either function A or function B I pass a relatively large array (It may be larger than 1x100, I just chose a number) and I do it many times. Note that I do actually need the functions A and B as functions as I need them in the function call (just called "function" here), you may use whatever you like, that is not the interesting part.

Now to the obvious problem, how do I speed this up?

One easy way to do it would be to simply hard code function A and function B into each for loop (in the sense that I copy the code into the for loop and avoid the function handle) and use some if statement to decide which one to go with, then I do not have to pass a matrix that many times. But first of all this is quite ugly and in reality I have many more function than just A and B.

Another way I thought of was to make multiple functions, one for each, but again it quickly becomes ugly as I have many functions and I want to keep the beauty of just having to change the function of interest in the beginning.

So does there exist any way to make this go faster, but still keeping the beauty and ease of just having to change the function of interest one time? 
I do of course parallelize the for loops, but it doesn't really solve the actual problem.

I have all matlab packages.

Comment: Just pass the arrays normally.  As long as you do not modify the array within the function, the array is passed by reference, which is the optimal course in this case.

Comment: That I am sorry to hear, because it takes about 10 times longer for the two first for loops and about 5 times longer for the third, if I hard code it. But I did fear, that this was the best shot.

Comment: That's odd.  If I inline the implementation of `A` as `P2(i) = sum(X)/length(X);`, the timing performance it comparable to a directly function call `A(X,1)`: 5.36 seconds versus 5.54 seconds.  The function handle `G` loop came in at 7.32 seconds, so I would avoid that handle if possible.

Comment: Also, what the line `a = function(@(x) A(x,0));` is trying to accomplish?  I (and m-lint) read that as invalid Matlab syntax.

Comment: That is also the problem I tried to describe. When I said hard code I meant that I copied the entire code from function A (or B) into the for loops.

As I write this is just some function which uses the determined function, in this case A, with the flag set to 0. For my sake you can use any function that you like. It is just to indicate that I need A as a function.

Comment: AS you have easily confirmed, the code using G is about twice slower than  the code using A directly, excluding the randn calls.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to tell, but the direct method is the fastest way. The results are consistent while having 1e6 calls. I've excluded the `randn` calls from each cycle:

Using No Functions at all

> Direct Call without Function: 20.38742 sec (1e7 calls)

Using Standard Functions

> Standard Function Call:       24.26631 sec (1e7 calls)

Using an Anonymous Handle

> Anonymous Function Call:      38.76371 sec (1e7 calls)

Using a Class as Handle

> Class as Handle:              211.4325 sec (1e7 calls)

The simpler, the better...

ps. Don't blame my machine. It just, works...

**EDIT**

Please note, that if you require to pass a function as argument, you can use any of -including but not being limited to- the following options, all of them able to be called as `G(x,flag)`, and all requiring to have the "named" function on the scope:

```
% Option 1
varfun=@(x,flag) A(x,flag);
G=varfun;

% Option 2
strfun='A(x,flag)';
eval(sprintf('G=@(x,flag) %s;',strfun));

% Option 3
namefun='A';
G=str2func(namefun);

% Option 4
strfun='A(x,flag)';
G=inline(strfun,'x','flag');

% Option 5
keyfun='A';
switch keyfun
    case 'A'
        G=@(x,flag) A(x,flag);
    case 'B'
        G=@(x,flag) B(x,flag);
end
```

Cheers

Comment: You can't ask me not to blame your machine without giving me alternatives. (which of course does not include myself). But thanks anyway for confirming my feeling.

Comment: Are there any way that I can take as input which function I will use. So i have [P1,P2,P3] = test(fun), and then when I call A i say fun(X,1). I know I can just send the fun as a function, but are there any way where I just pass the name of the function as it is already defined?